# JavaFX 8 SceneBuilder LineChart data type

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, scenebuilder

It seems like when I create a LineChart in SceneBuilder it defaults to "String". That is: `LineChart<String, String>`.

When I load it in code then try to add some data I get:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

It works fine if I create the chart in code instead:

```
val chart = new LineChart[Number, Number]( new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis())
```

I don't see any option in SceneBuilder that allows me to choose "Number" as the type of data the chart will have.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just edit the FXML generated by SceneBuilder in a text editor, for example, if you create a new LineChart in SceneBuilder 2, it will generate the following FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>

<LineChart xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:id="xychart">
  <xAxis>
    <CategoryAxis fx:id="xAxis" side="BOTTOM" />
  </xAxis>
  <yAxis>
    <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis" side="LEFT" />
  </yAxis>
</LineChart>
```

Edit it to change the line:

```
<CategoryAxis fx:id="xAxis" side="BOTTOM" />
```

to:

```
<NumberAxis fx:id="xAxis" side="BOTTOM" />
```

The chart will automatically reload in SceneBuilder (because it watches for edits to the FXML file) to include two number axes instead of a NumberAxis and a CategoryAxis.

Comment: Thank you ! didn't realise "CategoryAxis" points to the same thing

Comment: If this is necessary, SceneBuilder is not perfect.

Comment: Yes, SceneBuilder is not perfect.  I am very happy about that.  For many tasks, SceneBuilder is good enough.  If the developers had tried to make SceneBuilder perfect, I do not believe it would have been delivered with so many useful features, and I think we would not have it available for free use today. Some incidental thoughts on [studies in perfectionism](https://hbr.org/2018/12/the-pros-and-cons-of-perfectionism-according-to-research).